# I'm having trouble understanding what "開き直った、とも言いますが" means

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, conjugations

I wish I could formulate this question in a better way because there's a million people on here who have posted similar "don't know what this means, please tell me" and I don't mean this to be low effort, but when I've plugged away with various dictionaries, it seems like the verb 開き直る is to become serious or defiant (also read somewhere mention it as to turn on / to turn upon?) and とも言いますが I think is related to declaring or saying something (I tell you / I say / etc?).

This is from something I've been (very slowly) attempting to read and the context immediately before this text is a lighthearted romance tinged scene that read something along the lines of "she withdrew a little from me but it doesn't matter, I won't pull away" assuming I read it right, if that context helps with matters at all.

Thanks in advance, apologies if this is blindingly obvious.

Comment: Can you give us a sentence or two preceding the phrase?

Comment: Sure thing, I don't have the exact verbatim sentence at the moment, but I remember it being pretty much 90% this - "ちょっと引いてる？　いえ、でも、　私は引きません" which was then of course followed by "開き直った、とも言いますが。" on the next slide (as this is a visual novel). It was during a kiss scene if that helps further.

Comment: @benmartin93 Who said which line? Who kissed who?